# Why the registeration.html form is not rendering in DJANGO?

Tags: python, django, django-views

New to DJANGO.

I am having trouble with rendering my `registeration.html` page.

This is my project structure

```
auth_test
    |
    |-urls.py
    |-settings.py
big_app
    |
    |-admin.py
    |-forms.py
    |-models.py
    |-urls.py
    |-views.py
templates
media
static
```

This is my application `big_app`.

The `auth_test`  folder `urls.py` is

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from big_app import views
# from django.conf.urls import url, include ---> this is depreciated from Django 4.0 onwards
from django.urls import include,re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'big_app/',include('big_app.urls')),
]
```

now the urls.py of the `big_app` is

```py
from big_app import views
from django.urls import include, re_path

# TEMPLATE URLS

app_name = 'big_app'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^register/$',views.register, name='register')
]
```

The `views.py` has the code.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from big_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileForm

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request, "big_app/index.html")


def register(request):
    registered = False
    # breakpoint()
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            # hashing the password

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

            # setting up the one to one relationship with the user present in the admin perspective

            profile.user = user

            if "profile_pic" in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES["profile_pic"]

            profile.save()
            registered = True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(
        request,
        "big_app/resgisteration.html",
        {
            "user_form": user_form,
            "profile_form": profile_form,
            "registered": registered,
        },
    )
```

my `base.html` looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">DJANGO</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'big_app:register' %}">Register</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <div class="container">
    {% block body_block %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And my `resgisteration.html` looks like this.

```html
{% extends 'big_app/base.html' %}
{% load static  %}

{% block body_bloc %}



<div class="jumbotorn">
    <h1> Form </h1>
    {% if registered %}
        <h1> Thank you for registering </h1>
    
    {% else %}

    <h1> Register here  </h1>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" name="" value="register">

    </form>

    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock body_bloc %}
```

---

***Now I have identified the problem.***

- When the `base.html` is triggered the link is properly taken to `url/big_app/register`.
- But the `views.py` the `requests.method` is coming as `GET` not `POST`. That is why the page is not displaying the form.

---

But I am not able to fix this. Need Help. What changes need to be done, in the code.

Comment: typo in inherited template `body_bloc` vs `body_block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **base.html** file, you have created a block which is named "body_block", however, in your **resgisteration.html** file, you have made a typo and wrote "body_bloc" instead of "body_block". If you change it, it should render just fine.